# How do I set the maximum php memory limit

Tags: php, memory

How should I set 10GB of memory_limit?

Should I display it as

memory_limit=10G

or

memory_limit=10240M

Answer (score 2):

For only the current file you can write that script into your code:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','10240M');
```

but if you want to do it permanently then.

1. open your php.ini file
2. change `memory_limit = 10240M`

Answer (score 0):

You can have `memory_limit=-1` to allocate unlimited memory.
(The maximum your RAM can offer)